# JWTRefreshTokenBundle change user_identity_field Symfony 5.4 + ApiPlatform

Tags: symfony, jwt, api-platform.com, refresh-token

I am using : Symfony 5.4 + ApiPlatform + JWTRefreshTokenBundle 1.1

JWTRefreshTokenBundle  => https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle

I need to change this parameter "user_identity_field" but there is no way to change this :

- I tried to change the Yaml =>

  `gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:`

  `user_identity_field: email`

  `user_provider: app_user_provider`
- I tried to modify this function in my user provider (app_user_provider) entity User.php :

  `public function getUserIdentifier(): string`
  `{`

  `return (string) $this->id;`
   `}`

Right now the better I can get is to have the ID instead of the E-mail in the user name column in my database, but as soon as I try to refresh the token, I get this message => " 401 "Invalid credentials".

I am tried to have "ID" instead of "E-MAIL" as user_identity_field.

Has anyone found a solution ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sf 5,4+

```
#gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml

gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    user_identity_field: email
    ttl:      2592000
    firewall: login
    user_provider: security.user.provider.concrete.app_user_provider
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to change the app_user_provider in the security.yaml file :

```
app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: id
jwt:
        lexik_jwt:
            class: App\Entity\User
```

i think the problem is : symfony try to authneticate user with the app_user_provider and you have a conflict because id's are in your JWT but framework search for email.
For verify that you can check your tokens on : https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0):

The JWTRefreshTokenBundle (`gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle`) is build upon the [JWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) (`lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle`), which is the bundle that defines the `user_identity_field` configuration:

```yaml
# config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    user_identity_field: 'email'
```